# How can I run javascript file after dom manipulation made in another js file?

Tags: javascript, html, domcontentloaded

When I run my rails application and enter likeButton into the console it gives me Uncaught ReferenceError: likeButton is not defined
at :1:1
(anonymous) @ VM1591:1
I tried moving the script in html to head and body. I am currently trying to use DOMContentLoaded but it seems I'm missing something. My overall goal is to change the color of the button once pressed and also keep the color after page refresh. I am using sessionStorage for this process. I just want to make sure that likeButton variable is declared after html is loaded. If its possible to done in javascript only.

```
//first js file
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000"
const GPUS_URL = `${BASE_URL}/gpus`
const USERS_URL = `${BASE_URL}/users`

const gpuCollection = document.querySelector('#gpu-collection')

let wish = sessionStorage.getItem('wish');

class Gpu {
    constructor(gpuAttributes) {
        this.title = gpuAttributes.title;
        this.price = gpuAttributes.price;
        this.features = gpuAttributes.features;
        this.link = gpuAttributes.link;
        this.image = gpuAttributes.image;
        this.id = gpuAttributes.id;

    }

    render() {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('card');

        let h = document.createElement('h2');
        let t = document.createTextNode(`${this.title} ($${this.price})`);
        h.appendChild(t);
        div.appendChild(h);

        let h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        h1.classList.add('gpu-cat');
        h1.innerHTML = `${this.features}`;
        div.appendChild(h1);

        let button = document.createElement('button');
        button.classList.add('list_btn');
        button.innerHTML = '♡';
        div.appendChild(button);
        
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        a.href = `${this.link}`;
        a.target = '_blank';
        img.src = `${this.image}`;
        img.classList.add('gpu-image');
        a.appendChild(img);
        div.appendChild(a);
        gpuCollection.appendChild(div);
    }

}
```

```
//second js file
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){

let likeButton;

SignUp();
logInUser();
logOutUser();

function putGpusOnDom(gpuArray){
     gpuArray.forEach(gpu => {
       let newGpu = new Gpu(gpu)
        newGpu.render()
      }); 
         likeButton = document.querySelector("button"); 

                }  

function fetchGpus(){
            fetch(GPUS_URL)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(gpus => putGpusOnDom(gpus))
    }

const enableWish = () => {
            
            console.log(likeButton)
            sessionStorage.setItem('wish', 'red')
         }

 gpuCollection.addEventListener('click', function (){
            wish = sessionStorage.getItem('wish');
   
            if(wish !== 'red'){
                enableWish();
            }else{
                disableWish();
            }
        });

})
```

```
//html file
...
 <body>
<div id = "gpu-collection"></div>
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/Gpu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/index.js" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the button is not part of the original DOM but added by javascript it will not be there on DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Further more with `div.appendChild(button);` you appear to have not defined `div` in the code you have supplied to us.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to leave it out but I do include it in my original code.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a [mcve]? For the minimal part of that, you can probably exclude the login stuff, it doesn't look related to the issue.

Comment: I've just realized the implications of _When I run my rails application and enter **likeButton into the console** it gives me Uncaught ReferenceError: likeButton is not defined at :1:1 (anonymous) @ VM1591:1_ . As you've defined `likeButton` as `const` and me `let` I believe it is out of scope for direct entry into the console. See : https://ui.dev/var-let-const/

Comment: Use a `load` Event instead. Just make sure the code you want to effect the DOM executes before you run that other code.

Comment: I will work on a minimal reproducible example. thank you Jon P

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment the like button is not available on `DOMContentLoaded` if it is added dynamically. You need to wait until the button has been placed in the DOM

Use something like the following, I'm making some guesses here as there are some gaps in your code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){

//document.querySelector("button"); not yet available
//NOTE: The likeButton variable will ONLY be in scope INSIDE the event listener function
//      You will not be able to access directly in the console.
let likeButton;

SignUp();
logInUser();
logOutUser();

function putGpusOnDom(gpuArray){
     gpuArray.forEach(gpu => {
       let newGpu = new Gpu(gpu)
        newGpu.render()
      });
      //Now you have rendered the button it is available
      //CAUTION: querySelector("button") will grab the first button on the page 
      //         and ONLY the first button
      likeButton = document.querySelector("button");    
      //Log like button to console while it is still in scope.
      console.log(likeButton);
}  

function fetchGpus(){
            fetch(GPUS_URL)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(gpus => putGpusOnDom(gpus))
    }

const enableWish = () => {
            
            console.log(likeButton)
            sessionStorage.setItem('wish', 'red')
         }

})
```

Comment: I updated my code to fill in the gaps. I tried your method and I still get the same outcome. The button is not defined in the html file.